# What is the problem with my ajax Post or with code in my views.py file that the audio is not being retrieved

Tags: django, ajax, audio, audio-recording

I am currently working on a project in Django which records audio on the browser and send it to the server for communication. i have already recorded the audio but when i try to POST it using an ajax request, an empty dictionary is received in views.py.

here is my script where i have recorded the audio and tried to post an ajax request(record.html)

```
<form method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    {%csrf_token%}
    <audio scr="" name="audio" id="audio1"></audio><br>
    <input type="button" value="click me to record"  id="recordbtn">
    <input type="button" value="click me to stop record"  id="stopbtn">
</form>
var blob;
 navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true})
 .then(function success(stream){
    var options;
    try{
        options={memiType:'audio/webm;codecs=opus'};
    }
    catch{
        console.log('media type not supported')
    }
    mediaRecorder=new MediaRecorder(stream,options);
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable=DataAvailable;
    recordbtn.onclick = function() 
    {
        mediaRecorder.start();
        console.log('recoding started');
    }

    var chunks=[];
    function DataAvailable(event)
    {
        chunks.push(event.data);
        console.log('dataprocessed');
        var audio = document.getElementById('audio1');

        audio.controls = true;
        blob = new Blob(chunks , { 'type' : 'audio/webm; codecs=opus' });
        console.log(blob);
        chunks = [];
        var audioURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        audio.src = audioURL;
        console.log('src assigned');


        var token = '{{csrf_token}}';
        console.log(token);

        var fd=new FormData();
        fd.append('Blob1',blob);
        console.log(fd);
        console.log(fd.getAll('Blob1'));

        $.ajaxSetup({headers:{ "X-CSRFToken": token}})
        $.ajax(
            {
                url:"{%url 'record:voice2pg'%}",
                type:'POST',
                contentType:'audio/webm; codecs=opus',
                data:fd,
                processData:false,
                success:function(){ 
                alert('post successful')
                    }
            }

        )

    }

    stopbtn.onclick = function() 
    {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        console.log('recording stopeed');            
    }
 })
 .catch(function failure()
 {
    console.log('failure occured');
 }
 );
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def voice2(request):
    if request.method=='GET':
        return render(request,'record.html')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST' :
            print(request.POST)
            print(request.FILES)
            audio=request.FILES.get("Blob1")
            print(audio)
        return render(request, 'record.html')
```

I am new for working with audio.In my console i could see the blob that is appended with the formdata, then where am  wrong ?

the console screen of my browser [this is what i see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFJoV.png)

output:

```
(typ) C:\Users\KRISHNA DAVE\project\tempproject> python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 17 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
December 04, 2019 - 12:03:17
Django version 2.2.6, using settings 'tempproject.settings'
Starting ASGI/Channels version 2.3.1 development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
HTTP GET /voice2 200 [0.04, 127.0.0.1:49173]
<QueryDict: {}>
None
<MultiValueDict: {}>
None
HTTP POST /voice2 200 [0.01, 127.0.0.1:49173]
```

why an i receiving an empty dictionary?
is there a problem with the code ajax request? Please help me with the problem because i am new for using audio

Comment: The first thing is for you try to debug by console.log(fd) to see if it's empty. I haven't work with audio tag so i'm not sure if it can get from request.FILES

Comment: i have already done that, but i couldn't still understand the problem. i have changed the image of the console seen of browser for reference. Still thank you

Comment: The `contentType` of your ajax request is wrong. Don't set it to audio, it should be a normal multipart/form-data. Set it to `false`.

Comment: Thank you so much @dirkgroten it worked. Now its able to fetch the file in views